# How to say "marriage equality"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I'm looking for a good way to say "marriage equality" in Japanese.

I like to avoid the term "same-sex marriage" (同性婚{どうせいこん}) in English because I think that it has an implication that it is somehow different to "regular" marriage.

Am I forced into a roundabout way of saying it like "結婚が各性的指向に認められました" or something like that?

Comment: Do you mean words like "opposite-sex marriage" sounds unnatural in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Japanese Wikipedia literally translates this noun as 平等【びょうどう】結婚 ([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E6%80%A7%E7%B5%90%E5%A9%9A)), and some Japanese sites introduces 結婚の平等, 婚姻の平等, etc.

I think all of these are valid possibilities you can use, while 結婚の平等 seems to be the most prevailing, according to Google. But whichever you choose, you have to explain what it means first, because vast majority of Japanese speakers don't know these phrases. I personally haven't seen any claim that 同性婚 is a biased term. This situation may change within a few years, though.

I checked several Japanese sites which contains these keywords, including sites which actively support LGBT. Many of them just briefly introduce these terms using brackets as (literal) translations of "marriage equality", and then stick to 同性婚 or 同性間の結婚.

結婚が各性的指向に認められました doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't like the term same-sex marriage in English because I don't like the implication that it's different. It's all just marriage. To that end I use the term "marriage equality" when speaking English and was thinking of doing the same when speaking to a group in Japanese tomorrow.

Comment: As of mid 2016, unfortunately the concept of 結婚の平等 has not (yet) been widely recognized in Japan. Use this term only if you can explain what it means.